# What is the meaning of "palabra" in this context?

Tags: traducción, definiciones

I came across this sentence while reading, and the use of 'palabra' doesn't make sense to me:

> Y no es que quiera irme; palabra.

Although it brings up connotations of the very slang usage of [word](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=word) in English.

Comment: It's short for _'I give you my WORD (of honour)'_

Comment: @deStrangis: Thanks, but do you want to make this an answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is the same meaning as in English, or at least as I understood from urbandictionary. It means something like "I promise" or "I swear".

About its origin I would say it is a shortened form of "palabra de honor". Cheking RAE for "palabra de honor" it redirects you to the fifth definition of "palabra":

> . 5. f. Empeño que hace alguien de su fe y probidad en testimonio de lo que afirma.

Answer (score 4):

It's short for "te doy mi palabra", meaning "te lo prometo".

You can [see in RAE](http://dle.rae.es/palabra) that palabra means "promesa u oferta".